# Replace particular symbols

Tags: java, android

Hello friends I am getting a string

```
 [1-Sept-2012 13:20 1-Oct-2012 13:20  India , 1-Sept-2012 17:42 28-Sept-2012 17:42  India ]
```

I am trying to implement this code, but it is not working

```
string.replace(",", "$");
string.replace(" ", "@");
```

Expected Output:-

```
[1-Sept-2012 13:20@1-Oct-2012 13:20@India@$1-Sept-2012 17:42@28-Sept-2012 17:42  India@$]
```

Please help me with the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
String source = "[1-Sept-2012 13:20 1-Oct-2012 13:20  India , 1-Sept-2012 17:42 28-Sept-2012 17:42  India ]";
String dest = source.replace(",", "$").replace(" ", "@");
```

maybe you forgot to assign the result of `string.replace()` to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method returns a string, which is something you are not taking into account in your code. Doing something like so should work:

```
String string = ...;
string = string.replace(",", "$").replace(" ", "@");
```

Answer (score 0):

**`String` is an immutable object**, you cannot change it<sup>1</sup>.

You need to assign the new string object back to the variable in order to "see" the affect.

```
string = string.replace(",", "$");
```

This creates a new `String` object and assign the new object to the variable `string`.

---

(1) not easily anyway, it can be done with reflection - but it is unadvised.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as below, also use `contains()` that will help to prevent errors.

```
String str="-------your string here---";

if(str.contains(","))
    str =str.replace(",", "$");

if(str.contains(""))
   str=str.replace(" ", "@");
```